# Creating a copy of a google form response to be sent to a column in the response google sheet

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm trying to email a copy of a google form response from an associate to their manager automatically using a google form response "Please provide your manager's email address" using Google App Script. And I'm definitely doing something incorrectly because it keeps failing at line 3. I did successfully create the "on Form Submit" trigger

[Code I have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V9Xw.png)

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {

  let sheetName = e.range.getSheet("Retail Bank Data Change Management Exception Form").getName();
  if (sheetName = "Retail Bank Data Change Management Exception Form") {

    let eventVals = e.namedValues;
    let emailAddress = eventVals["Please provide your manager's email address"].toString();

    if (emailAddress != "Please provide your manager's email address") {

      let bodyText = "";
      let keys = Object.keys(eventVals);

      keys.forEach((key, index) => {
        bodyText += `${key}: ${eventVals[key]}\n`;
      });

      let subject = "Your associate has submitted an exclusion request to the Data Element Change Management Portal.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, bodyText);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post you code as text instead of an image.

Comment: e.range.getSheet() does not accept any parameters

Answer (score 0):

In my forms my questions are all numbered so I filter out all keys that don't have a number and I also sort the questions by that same number.  Perhaps this will work for you.

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  let keys = Object.keys(e.namedValues).filter(k => k.match(/^\d{1,}/)).sort((a, b) => {
    //console.log('a: %s b: %s', Number(a.slice(0, a.indexOf('.'))), Number(b.slice(0, b.indexOf('.'))));
    return Number(a.slice(0, a.indexOf('.')) - Number(b.slice(0, b.indexOf('.'))));
  });
  let text = "";
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    text += `${key}: ${e.namedValues[key]}\n`;
  });
  //console.log(text);
}
```